# Computed Observable In ReactiveKit/Bond

Tags: swift, reactivekit, swiftbond

Is there some kind of [Computed Observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) in [ReactiveKit](https://github.com/ReactiveKit/ReactiveKit#subjects) Or [Bond](https://github.com/ReactiveKit/Bond)?

Does initializing an Observable with a native Swift computed property will act the same?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it like this:

```
class Person {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    private var fullNameBG: Observable<String>
    var fullName: Observable<String> {
        computedPropBG.next("\(firstName) \(lastName)")
        return computedPropBG
    }
    init() {
        fullNameBG = Observable("")
    }
}
```

Will be glad to hear a better solution.

Comment: It feels to me that you can use MVP or MVVM pattern to create an additional layer with observables.